# JavaScript: Set name of inner function to be name of variable it's assigned to

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do some composition and I'm using the function name to assign a key in an object. Thus, I have a higher order function kind of like so:

```
function doThing(fn) {
  return function (...args) {
     return fn(...args);
  };
}
```

And I'm assigning the result of the outer function to a variable:

```
var coolThing = doThing(someFunction);
```

I want `coolThing.name` to equal `'coolThing'`.

Now I'm pretty sure that is impossible because once the inner function is returned, the name is set to an empty string and can no longer be changed. But I'm wondering if I can elegantly make something like it work without skirting the lexer or anything awful like that.

Just wrapping `doThing(someFunction)` with another function would make it work, but that ends up making it no better than what I had started with.

It doesn't have to be the name property that I'm using, but the function needs to have some property that get's its value from the name of the variable.

Any ideas, or am I trying to be too cute here?

Comment: So inside of doThing, you think you can get the name of the variable coolThing? I doubt it....

Comment: I guess you don't want to pass in the name as another argument to `doThing`

Comment: *"It doesn't have to be the name property"* - Well you could assign any custom property to the function that you like, e.g., `coolThing.myName = "coolThing"`, and you could do it inside your `doThing()` function if you passed the function name in as another argument, or used the name of the function you are already passing as an argument. (But then if you create some other variable that references the same function like `anotherVar = coolThing` you'd find that `anotherVar.myName` would still be equal to `"coolThing"`.)

Answer (score 1):

> I'm pretty sure that is impossible

You're right. The variable name is not accessible programmatically, and for sure not inside `doThing`. Even for function declarations and assigned anonymous function expressions, the implicitly assigned `.name` property is something that the runtime does extract from the source text for exactly those syntactic constructs. It can not be intercepted and should only be used for debugging purposes anyway.